# SSIS: path,file name, or both are too long. name must be less than 260 characters,directory name must be less than 248 characters

Tags: ssis

I am getting the error message though my filename is 145 characters. Many thanks in advance, the other posted solution did not help me.

Note: I am getting error message in the last line, when I am trying to copy the file.

```
        string source_directory = Dts.Variables["User::package_directory"].Value.ToString().Trim();
        string archive_directory = Dts.Variables["User::package_archive_directory"].Value.ToString().Trim();
        string package_name = Dts.Variables["User::package_name"].Value.ToString().Trim();
        string file_name = Dts.Variables["User::package_associated_filename"].Value.ToString().Trim();

        int pos = file_name.IndexOf('.');
        string filename_without_extension = file_name.Substring(0, pos);
        string file_extension = file_name.Substring(pos);

        //MessageBox.Show(file_extension.ToString());
        string date_now = DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").Trim();
        string source_file = source_directory + file_name;
        string destination_file = archive_directory + filename_without_extension + date_now + file_extension;
        System.IO.File.Copy(source_file, destination_file,  true);
```

Comment: I made a mistake. Basically my file_name was pulling the directory information as well. At the end the source_file and destination_file string was becoming really long. 

It is human error.

Comment: Do not use substring and such to calculate file name without extensions, etc. There are rich methods in the System.IO namespace - specifically Directory and Path. Those libraries will be much more robust than the code you have written